# having one spinner in each card view - card view in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am following this tutorial https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-recyclerview-cardview-tutorial/ However my requirements are different. 
Instead of having set values like a name, description, rating like the tutorial has, I  am wanting to have a spinner, edit text, textbox and checkbox in each Cardview. (when the user presses the FAB button, another card view is added, which also has a spinner, textbox, checkbox and edit text)

But the thing is, the spinner is populated by items in a csv file and this is where I am having trouble. I have a previous program file without card view and recycler view, where the spinners are populated with csv file values and when you press the FAB, spinner appears. However im having trouble integrating the recycler view with this.

In my previous program file I had a MyListAdapter.java.This is the adapter for the spinner i believe.

```
public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    int groupid;
    List<String> items;
    Context context;
    String path;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int vg, int id, List<String> items) {
        super(context, vg, id, (List<String>) items);
        this.context = context;
        groupid = vg;
        this.items = items;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textid;
        public TextView textname;

    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        {

            View rowView = convertView;
            if (rowView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                rowView = inflater.inflate(groupid, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.textid = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
                viewHolder.textname = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtname);
                rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            // Fill data in the drop down.
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
            String row = items.get(position);
            //holder.textid.setText(row[0]); //prints aisle number, dont need

            holder.textname.setText(row);



            return rowView;
        }

    }

}
```

Additionally then, in my mainacttivity I had this code which read the csv file.

```
  private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {

            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    //TODO I edited this part so that you'd add the values in our new hash map variable
                    numberItemValues.put(row[1], row[0]);
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }
```

But the tutorial asks for a two classes, Product.java and product adapter.java. (if you click the tutorial you will see their code) I am confused how to integrate my code above with this tutorial situation?

Comment: is the spinner values different for any item in recyclerview?

Comment: card views are dynamically added to the recycler view when fab pressed. Each card view has a spinner. the values in each spinner of each card view are the same. (They values are all from the same csv file)

Answer (score 1):

*-first of all create your recyclerview row layout xml file with items you want

*-load csv file in your main activity or fragment and pass them to your adapter, declare a parameter in your adapter constructor

*-inside your recuclerview adapter class, in onCreateViewHolder method inflate that layouts(just like example)

*-in your RecyclerView.ViewHolder constructor get all your comonent like Spinner and etc, just like example

```
TextView textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
...
Spinner spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```

*-in your onBindViewHolder method fill spinner with loaded csv file, same as before

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);//mContext should be passed from your activity to your adapter, so you should add it to your adapter constructor
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need a custom adapter for your spinner if all you need is to display a simple spinner with list of strings. Add the following snippet to your `onBindViewHolder()` method to populate your spinner.

```
String[] dataArray = new String[]{"Spinner data1", "data 2"}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataArray);
    holder.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Read the tutorial and follow every steps including creating a `Product.java` class. Create a layout and replace the `layout_product.xml` with the new layout. I have created one for you below, copy the code and rearrange the components to meet your want and paste it in the new layout file. Lets call the new file, `card_layout`.

> card_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:padding="7dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Hey, its me"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I don't understand the TextBox part, but you can add it yourself if its not already the above code snippet. Now, replace the layout in recyclerview adapter with the new layout. It should work now.